# Error in the date time format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, date-format, strptime

My Python code is showing an error in the date time format. What should be the correct format for this type of date: '09-Jul-11 12:00:00 AM'?
The date is taken as a string from a text file.
This is the code I used for date and time.

```
date=datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%B-%y %H:%M:%S %p")
```

This was the error I got.

```
ValueError: time data '09-Jul-11 12:00:00 AM' does not match format '%d-%B-%y %H:%M:%S %p'
```

P.S.: I am using Python 3.

Comment: You need to consult documentation before coming here. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: ... and read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It's the wrong format for month and hour. Use `%b` instead of `%B` (month as locale's abbreviated name[1]) and `%I` instead of `%H` (12-hours format).

```
date=datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

[1]: thank to Ricky Han's comment

Comment: %b Month as locale’s abbreviated name. 
Jan, Feb, ..., Dec (en_US);

Answer (score 0):

[Online Demo](https://repl.it/IkdM)
`%b` should be used for abbreviated month name.You have used `%B` which is used for full month name.

`%H` is used for hour, using a 24-hour clock (00 to 23).`%I` is used for hour, using a 12-hour clock (01 to 12)

```
import datetime
date = '09-Jul-11 12:00:00 AM'
date=datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y %I:%M:%S %p")
print(date)
```

Comment: @Błotosmętek Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct format string is: `"%d-%b-%y %I:%M:%S %p"` (`%b` for abbreviated month, `%I` for 12-hours clock).